# Creating HLS from pre-encoded files

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have a bunch of pre-encoded files and I want to create HLS with ffmpeg.

```
h264_baseline_144p_150.mp4
h264_baseline_360p_400.mp4
h264_main_480p_800.mp4
h264_main_720p_1500.mp4
h264_high_1080p_3000.mp4
audio.mp4
```

Video files have only 1 video stream (no audio).
Here are some flags that I want to use.

```
-hls_flags single_file -hls_time 1
```

I've spent some time reading documentation https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-hls-2 but it's supposed to have some background to make use out of it...

I need help with writing command.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Please help what?

Comment: with writing command that turns a bunch of separate mp4 into HLS structure.